# Inspecting memory values in DDD

Tags: assembly, nasm, ddd-debugger

In `DDD`, if I try to access a variable via `x $value` I get the error **Value can't be converted to integer**

Can u tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is my example:

```
section .data
value dd 3
result dd 0h

section .text
global main
main:
mov ebx,4
add ebx,[value]
mov [result],ebx

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
According to https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_Languages/x86-64_Assembly_Language_Programming_with_Ubuntu_(Jorgensen)/06%3A_DDD_Debugger/6.02%3A_Program_Execution_with_DDD

you have to use the following syntax:

```
x/db    &bnum1
x/dh    &wnum2
x/dw    &dnum3
x/dg    &qnum
x/s     &class
x/f     &twopi
```

Example:

```
x/dd &value1
```